# Display data of database with (JS And Html and Css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on creating this:

https://oreplains.fr/server

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVrmt.jpg

I have the same code, but it doesn't show anything.

Code:

- [html](https://hastebin.com/tedituyesa.xml)
- [shops.js](https://hastebin.com/araxisipoz.js)
- [blocks_items.css](https://hastebin.com/arepabisih.css)

The problem is it doesn't show anything. I'd like to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVrmt.jpg).

Comment: `var Html = "https://hastebin.com/tedituyesa.xml"` same the next too

Comment: But i tried with the same web html and nothing i see white i dont see the items..

Comment: sorry i miss understand your question, see my answer.

Comment: u js is call to >> https://oreplains.fr/survival_shop.db

Comment: or u can just write u own ajax code

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because inside of the `shops.js` there is an ajax request to `https://oreplains.fr/survival_shop.db`. because of cross origin rules, the request is failed.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: And how can i change that to my file example C:ussers/desktop/surivva_shop.js

Comment: You can't sorry, you can make a proxy in expressjs or php or any other language, but you need a web server for that, but this is out of topic from the original question.

Comment: Hey its not working i do xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/survival_shop.db', true);